# How to save Excel file without showing save dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello i try to save the excel file with my path that automoticly but when i save it,i get pop up with save as mothod this my code.
How to i save this file with path that i need aoutomaticly

```
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRng;
                object misvalue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                try
                {
                    //Start Excel and get Application object.
                    oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    oXL.Visible = true;

                    //Get a new workbook.
                    oWB = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(""));
                    oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

                    //Add table headers going cell by cell.
                    oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "First Name";
                    oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Last Name";
                    oSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Full Name";
                    oSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Salary";

                    //Format A1:D1 as bold, vertical alignment = center.
                    oSheet.get_Range("A1", "D1").Font.Bold = true;
                    oSheet.get_Range("A1", "D1").VerticalAlignment =
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;

                    // Create an array to multiple values at once.
                    string[,] saNames = new string[5, 2];

                    saNames[0, 0] = "John";
                    saNames[0, 1] = "Smith";
                    saNames[1, 0] = "Tom";
                    saNames[1, 1] = "Brown";

                    oXL.Visible = true;
                    oXL.UserControl = true;

oWB.SaveAs("c://Vova/test34545.xls", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
oWB.Close();
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure but this is not achievable , you need to use ActiveX control to do it.

Comment: @Devesh: That's what the op is using.

Comment: try with `c:\\Vova\\test34545.xls`

Comment: @Vova: Please indicate whether you are trying to save the file to the server or to the client.

Comment: I changed  path to c:\\Vova\\test34545.xls and  oXL.Visible = false;
 oXL.UserControl = false; and this works

Comment: I recommend [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/),which is much easier and you can export data to excel even without installing MS Office on your PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the path to  `c:\\Vova\\test34545.xlsx` and then disable pop up set :

```
oXL.Visible = false;
oXL.UserControl = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

        xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "ArsalanQaiser";
        string fileName = "Excel.xls";
        string path = "D:\\" + fileName;
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(path, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/Excel");
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
            Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The op has not specified if they are trying to save the file to the server or to the client.